# How To Buffer Many Vertex, Geometry, and Pixel Shaders

Tags: c++, c++11, directx, shader, directx-11

What is the best way to buffer Vertex Shaders, Pixel Shaders, etc into the Device/Device Context without having to reload them from the filesystem every time?

ID3D11Device::CreateVertexShader
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476524(v=vs.85).aspx

ID3D11DeviceContext::VSSetShader
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476493(v=vs.85).aspx

Does Device::CreateVertexShader buffer a single instance of the shader in System, (not GPU), memory?  Can I buffer more than 1?

DeviceContext::CreateVertexShader buffer a single instance of the shader in the GPU, (not System), memory?  Can I buffer more than 1?

What are the recommended methods for buffering shaders within the system?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get the idea that you could only create one vertex shader at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use ID3D11Device::CreateVertexShader, you retrieve a reference to them, will represents your vertex shader in gpu, so if you have 3 vertex shaders you do:

```
ID3D11VertexShader* vsref1;
ID3D11VertexShader* vsref2;
ID3D11VertexShader* vsref3;

CreateVertexShader(bytecode1,sizeofbytecode1,NULL,&vsref1);
CreateVertexShader(bytecode2,sizeofbytecode2,NULL,&vsref2);
CreateVertexShader(bytecode3,sizeofbytecode3,NULL,&vsref3);
```

Make sure you keep track of vsref1,2 and 3 (like as class members). Once created they are uploaded to your gpu, no need to do it again, VSSetShader is then called to select which one you want to use.

Then you can assign your vertex shader to the pipeline anytime using:

```
VSSetShader(vsref1,NULL,0);
```

or

```
VSSetShader(vsref2,NULL,0);
```

That doesn't cause an upload, it's just to tell your gpu which Vertex Shader you want to use for the next Draw call.

Comment: This is awesome!  Does VertexShaderPtr->Release() remove the shader from the GPU then?  I don't suppose you know, in general, where I could find a diagram, doc, explaining the interactions between CPU and GPU memory, buffers, etc?  "This method instances the shader in CPU memory, this one binds it to the GPU memory, this one sets it to active... but for things like vertex buffers, constants, but more importantly, resources and textures.  I really appreciate all of your help!

Comment: Yes Release will remove it from the GPU (please note all directx objects are reference counters by the way), about diagrams I got slides from different presentations about dx11 rendering, I could send you a link if you want. I also have some tutorials in the making but they are not published yet (some using c#/SlimDX, some using raw c++/dx11)

Comment: I had been thinking that Create methods in general make a CPU hosted buffer, while Set does the binding to the GPU.  It seems as though you are saying that Create is what Binds, and Set is what makes buffers, textures, etc, active.  Buffers work the same way then?  CreateVertexBuffer creates a GPU hosted buffer, while IA Set Buffers just changes the active buffers, etc?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Create does make a GPU buffer (since you also provide data for it), so it allocates GPU memory, and upload CPU data into GPU. Set tells the GPU to use that buffer (think about a pointer sitting in gpu). gpu data is already there, it's just to tell that it will need to use it.